# Launching a designed for iPad mac app crashes at startup: Library not loaded

Tags: ios, macos, build

After making my app on iOS with an iPad version, I want to launch the mac version with my M1 mac.

> dyld[49831]: Library not loaded:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ActivityKit.framework/ActivityKit
>
> Reason: tried:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/ActivityKit.framework/ActivityKit' (no such
> file)

I can understand that ActivityKit is not a macOS library, but how can I remove it from the build?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to mark the linked framework as optional?

Comment: @lazarevzubov I haven't had to add in the settings so I'm unsure how to put it as optional

Comment: In Xcode, open your project file, pick your target, open the "Build Phases" tab, find the framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, in the "Status" column pick "Optional."

Comment: By default, building an app without having them inside "Link Binary With Libraries" is not an issue. Adding them in manually then putting them as optional did the trick. Thanks! Please answer the question and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For such cases, you can link the framework optionally: Pick your target in Xcode, go to the "Build Phases" tab, find the framework in the "Link Binary With Libraries" section, and in the "Status" column, pick "Optional."

Comment: This does not work for me. I added ActivityKit.framework to 'Link Binary with Libraries' and set it to Optional. The app still crashes.

Comment: @RickyKresslein Are you sure then that your crash is related to unavailability of ActivityKit?

Comment: it seems so, I am getting the same error mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

This might be useful if you do not want to execute some codes about Activity on My Mac(Designed for iPhone). `if ProcessInfo.processInfo.isiOSAppOnMac {}`